# Breaking down statement in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Anyone mind helping me break down this statement in discrete mathematics?

Having trouble understanding if I'm doing this correctly or not.

The original statement was:

~(~p -> q) -> (p v r)

And I went on:

[image: Work i've done so far]

Comment: Correct, but the 4th and 5th lines are superfluous : you can go from $\lnot (p \lor q) \to (p \lor r)$ to $\lnot \lnot (p \lor q) \lor (p \lor r)$ and then...

Answer (score 1):

You've done fine.  A tip, though, following your third step: third statement:

$$\lnot (p\lor q) \rightarrow (p\lor r)\tag{3}$$

$$ \equiv \lnot\lnot (p\lor q) \lor (p \lor r)\tag 4$$

$$\equiv (p\lor q)\lor (p\lor r)\tag 5$$ $$\equiv p\lor q \lor p \lor r \tag{(6) associativity of $\lor$}$$

$$\equiv \underbrace{p \lor p}_{\large \equiv p} \lor q \lor r\tag{(7) commutativity of $\lor$}$$

$$\equiv p\lor q\lor r\tag 8 $$

Answer (score 0):

Well that's correct. Now all you need as a final step is:
$$
p \lor q \lor r
$$
Since you have $$\lor$$ everywhere, you can eliminate brackets.